# Google Sheet Auto Add / Update Value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm using Google Forms to collect a data. So, there was one question in the Google Form that I considered as a primary key when using the VLOOKUP function. However, there is a possibility that some data will collect zero (0) for the answer since they do not have an official ID number yet. I'm wondering if there is a way for me to automatically add or update a value when the value is zero (0). I'm thinking of using an temporary ID which letters and numbers. Ex: ID000001

[image: SAMPLE PICTURE]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. Can you provide the sample input and output situations as the image?

Comment: @Tanaike I already put a sample image. Please check.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a sample script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert `0` to `ID000001`. And, when the multiple `0` values are existing, you want to convert to `ID000001`, `ID000002`,,,.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  let c = 1;
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => [a === 0 ? `ID${(c++).toString().padStart(6, '0')}` : a]);
  range.setValues(values);  
}
```

- In this script, it supposes that the column of "STUDENT ID" is the column "A" because I cannot know the column information from your sample image.

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [padStart()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)

### Added:

From your following additional question,

> Wait. If I run again the script, the output is starting again with ID000001. Is there a way for me to just continue the number?

In this case, how about using PropertiesServices as follows?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  const p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  const count = p.getProperty("count");
  let c = count ? Number(count) : 1; // If you want to set the initial count, please modify 1 to other.
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => [a === 0 ? `ID${(c++).toString().padStart(6, '0')}` : a]);
  range.setValues(values);
  p.setProperty("count", c);
}

// When you want to reset the count, please run this function.
function reset() {
  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().deleteProperty("count");
}
```

For example, when all `ID######` values are updated every run, you can also use the following sample script.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange("A2:A" + sheet.getLastRow());
  range.createTextFinder("^ID[\\d]+$").matchEntireCell(true).useRegularExpression(true).replaceAllWith(0);
  let c = 1;
  const values = range.getValues().map(([a]) => [a === 0 ? `ID${(c++).toString().padStart(6, '0')}` : a]);
  range.setValues(values);
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you!

Comment: Wait. If I run again the script, the output is starting again with ID000001. Is there a way for me to just continue the number?

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. About your additional question, I added one more sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question, I apologize.

Comment: @cjwrk For example, when all `ID######` values are updated every run, please check my bottom sample script.

Comment: It's working! I'm going to use the last one. Thank you!

Comment: @cjwrk Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. I thought that the last sample script might be more flexible than others.